# Cppreference's complexity?

Tags: c++

I am starting to understand notations of algorithmic time complexity, like the "big O". However, I do not understand many of the descriptions of different algorithmic complexities on cppreference, [like for std::search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search). It does not involve the notations that I have finally learnt, such as "big O" and "big Omega".. How should I interpret complexity descriptions like this?

> At most `S*N` comparisons where `S = std::distance(s_first, s_last)` and `N = std::distance(first, last)`.

Comment: It says "At most S*N comparisons" which is same as `O(S*N)` by definition, which part is confusing? `std::distance`?

Comment: When you read `O(N)` for linear complexity - what is N? If you have two sequences of different lengths, how do you decide which is N?

Comment: It says "At most S*N comparisons" which **implies** "`O(S*N)` for the worst-case scenario".

Comment: @Kos it's not the same thing. `S*N` is `O(S*N)`, but `O(S * N)` is not always `<= S * N`

Comment: @Kos/YSC It doesn't imply `O(S*N)` unless you can know a comparison is `O(1)`. This is not required, and with certain standard library types not true in practice.

Comment: @hvd Good luck finding an example where a comparison between two elements of a container depends on the size of the container.

Comment: @YSC It doesn't need to depend on the size of the container, it can depend on the size of the elements (think of string comparisons). It's incorrect to say that `std::search` in that case is `O(S*N)`.

Comment: @hvd Well, yes. A bit like [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back#Complexity) is not in O(1) since it depends on the complexity of the copy operator. We tend not to take that in consideration, do we?

Comment: @YSC I do tend to take that in consideration. Good example where cppreference (and the standard) doesn't. The standard usually specifies which functions are called and how often they're called, avoiding the problem.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. But how about this: ["Approximately (last-first)log(middle-first) applications of cmp"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort#Complexity)? How would that be translated?

Comment: @hvd Ho yes, I should have said that. It says "At most S*N comparisons" which **implies** a complexity of `O(N*S)` times the mean-complexity of `operator==` of `std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt1>::value_type`. That's a mouthful though.

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what is written. It will do no more then `S*N` comparisons for inputs of lengths `S` and `N`. e.g if you have arrays of length 5 and 3 it will do no more then 15 comparisons:

```
std::array<char, 3> a;
std::array<char, 5> b;
std::search(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that big O notation describes the *asymptotic upper bound* on complexity, and generally just the way complexity scales with respect to a single variable. Where there are multiple variables, they're assumed to be independent, and they all tend to infinity together.

It doesn't describe the exact number of operations for small values of N, or provide any way to describe functions with multiple types of operation which may have different runtime cost, and if you have multiple but non-independent variables it doesn't show their relationship until you reduce the form yourself.

In this case, you have two variables, and the asymptotic complexity depends on which of them are varying, and which dominates. So, we can call it `O(S*N)`, but in these examples we could do better:

1. I'm searching for a fixed-length sub string in ever-longer source string. In this case `S` remains constant and so `O(S*N) ≃ O(N) as N→∞`.
2. I'm searching for a fractional subset of my ever-longer source string, say `S = N/K` for some constant K. Now I'm interested in `O(S*N) = O(N²/K) ≃ O(N²) as N→∞`.

So the description

> At most `S*N` comparisons where `S = std::distance(s_first, s_last)` and `N = std::distance(first, last)`.

is much more informative than `O(S*N)`, and not only because it applies to *all* `S` and `N` rather than only to "sufficiently large" values.

Comment: If either way, you can describe it as `O(S*N)`, then big-O notation is perfectly adequate.

Comment: If `S` is constant, you _should_ decay it to `O(N)`. If S is proportional to `N`, you _should_ write it as `O(N²)`. Writing `O(S*N)` without also explaining how S and N vary is unhelpful, since it implicitly means `N` is increasing and says nothing about how `S` behaves.

Comment: To say it means `N` is increasing is just plain silly. You wouldn't say that after calling `std::max` (assuming that with the concrete comparer in use this is `O(N)` operation) on a range of length 4, you can no longer call it on a range of length 3, would you?

Comment: _Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behaviour of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity_. Admittedly that's from Wikipedia, but asymptotic complexity is specifically all about how things scale as the argument becomes arbitrarily large. Note the use of the singular "argument": the notation has nothing to say about two arguments, so you have to reduce to whichever dominates approaching the limit.

Comment: Yes, so when the argument is `S*N`, it describes how the function behaves when `S*N` grows arbitrarily large, without implying that either `S` or `N` will actually change, and without implying that they won't change. A quick search for examples gives https://stackoverflow.com/q/11937919 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/96809. `O(S*N)` is perfectly normal notation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know that my question has already been answered. However, what does [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) then mean in terms of notations? Would it simply be O(N/2)?

Comment: @hvd - yes, the multivariate notation gives you the asymptotic complexity _as all variables tend to infinity_ (ie, "increase", despite that being apparently plain silly). I'm saying that tells you nothing useful about the actual behaviour of your program, because it discards information about the way those variables actually behave. This is, after all, why we're using big-O notation in the first place, right? To see roughly how a program will behave?

Comment: @Rocket - "At most N/2 swaps ... about 3 comparisons and 1.5 swaps per call" is still linear complexity. It's giving you _more_ information than `O(N)` alone, because you can reason about (or benchmark) the cost of each type of operation, where big-O just gives you the rough shape for arbitrarily large N.

Comment: So if you wrote it in complexity notations (like "big O" and "big Theta"), it would not include all the information given? But what _would_ you write if you absolutely had to rewrite it to complexity notations?

Comment: @Useless Indeed for your second part. The same logic holds for `O(N)` when `N` is constant in a particular program. In that case `O(N)` by itself doesn't tell you anything useful, it's only when you combine it with the fact that `N` *won't* grow arbitrarily large that it's useful. That doesn't make the `O(N)` notation wrong. For the first part, no, `O(S*N)` says something about when `S*N` grows arbitrarily large, which happens when *either* `S` or `N` grows arbitrarily large (and the other is non-zero).

Comment: Big-O notation is not a magic panacea for encoding all your performance information, it is just - and very specifically - a way of describing the rough shape of a function as it tends to a limit. If you know you really just need to compare 4 things, writing that as `O(N)` or `O(4)` or whatever achieves _nothing_. You just need to worry about whether or not those 4 ops are fast enough for you.

Comment: So you would write the complexity as "O(N)" and not "O(N/2)"? I do get what you are saying about the loss of information. However, it would be nice to know what you _could_ write in terms of formal notations.

Comment: Yes - the whole point is that N dominates the term `N/2` as N gets big. Which is to say, roughly, the steepness of a straight line doesn't affect its essential straight line-y-ness. Read the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations) and choose a different notation if you want to express something else, or just write it in English. Big-O notation _only_ tells you the asymptotic upper bound. That's how it is defined, and that's all it means.